# Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream reads a property file multiple times

Tags: java

I have a property file named sysconfig.properties, I want to read it multiple times, because it is mutable.But I found when I changed the content of the sysconfig.properties then I read the content that is imutable, which is the same with the first time I read from the systemconfig.properties file.The content of the sysconfig.propertes file as follows:

```
isInitSuccess=TRUE
isStartValid=2013
```

May be sometime it will been changed as follows:

```
isInitSuccess=FALSE
isStartValid=2013
```

The code of read the properties file as follows:

```
InputStream inStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath);
```

I use the code read the file mutilple times, but every time the "isInitSuccess" is "TRUE", even though I changed the isInitSuccess=FALSE.Is the system just read it one time, then I read the file, it just get the input stream from the memory?
But when I use the code below, it will work fine:

```
InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(new File(strPath));
```

I googled, but I did not find any help, the problem confused me a lot, any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read up on what the classpath is.

In short, Java has a concept of classpath which includes all the resources (`.class` files, `.properties` files, and anything really) it needs to run. When you use `ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream(String)`, you're actually getting the `InputStream` of a classpath resource. This resource can be a physical resource on disk or it can be in an archive.

When you use a `FileInputStream`, you are getting the `InputStream` of a file on disk.

The `InputStream` from the `ClassLoader` and the one from the `FileInputStream` do not correspond to the same file.

You should read up on how your IDE (or whatever build system) handles your files.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you tell me a lot about classpath(I am a green hand of java develop)."The InputStream from the ClassLoader and the one from the FileInputStream do not correspond to the same file." which is right.But in my specific circumstance they correspond to the same file.May be there are some files both called sysconfig.properties files in my claspath, but the content of the files must be the same.the content is:
    isInitSuccess=TRUE
    isStartValid=2013
But when I changed the content as follows:
    isInitSuccess=TRUE*************
    isStartValid=2013**************

Comment: then I stoped the program and restart it, both The InputStream from the ClassLoader and the one from the FileInputStream read the content is the same, so I can promise they read the same file.